# Gimp 2.10.10 plugins for Windows 10

Tags: gimp, plugin

I'm looking for one or more reliable sources where I can find plugins, brushes etc. I'm using Gimp 2.10.10.

Often I get rid of the objects, I used "content aware fill" with Photoshop and it was very useful, I had read that Gimp had "Resynthesizer", but, since I have to upgrade to version 2.10.12, I would like to use Partha's version, in which GMIC has "inpainting". Does it work the same way?

BTW,are there watercolour brushes?

I'm not an expert, are there guides to learn how to use GMIC, Nik etc.?

Before upgrading to the Partha version, should I uninstall 2.10.10?

Please, someone can help me and give me some advices

Comment: Welcome to **GD.SE** - ***Please*** look through **[tour]** to get a sense of what our community is about; *then* look over **[ask]** and **[answer]** a question to see what makes a **good** query here, *and* how best to frame it. We *tend* to prefer that questions not be basically tech support for App X; yours seems perilously close to that as currently framed. Please read [ask] and see if you can then revise your question to better fit our guidelines. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Data add-ons for Gimp 2.18 (brushes, palettes, gradients...) can still be used for 2.10.

Many "scripts" (.scm) will still work. Others may require minor editing. This is also true of Python (.py) plugins.

Compiled plugins (.exe) are a different matter. Really a hit or miss. The plugins written for previous versions may not support the high-precision images. The easy solution is to install a Gimp build from [partha.com](https://partha.com/) since these come with the more popular compiled plugins pre-installed.

Comment: ,I already have Gimp 2.10.10 installed, so can I download G'MIC, Nik Collection? Can you tell me if Resynthesizer is included? because before I used Photoshop " content aware fill". What do you think of Krita? is an alternative to Gimp? can both be used? please suggest me what is best to do, because, as I said, I am a true beginner.Thank you

Comment: Please check Partha's site. His stuff includes GMIC and Nik. IIRC resynthesize is also include, but you have the same functionality in GMIC (aka "inpainting"). Since the latest is 2.10.12, you have to upgrade anyway...